# " SyntaxError: Unexpected token { " when trying to debug unit tests of angular 8 in VS code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug angular unit tests in VS code. I have added two break points(BP1,BP2) in app.component.spec.ts to check the debugging.

```
       it('should create the app', () => {
BP1--->    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
BP2--->    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
           expect(app).toBeTruthy();
       });
```

But I was getting the error like

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\neethu.kp\test\test-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\neethu.kp\test\test-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\neethu.kp\test\test-app\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:93:5
```

Then, I tried to debug by changing the 'module' property to 'commonjs' in tsconfig.json , at that time it is showing another error like

```
" Failed: Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js "
```

I have added configuration files of my angular projects below. 
Please help me to fix this issue..

launch.json

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        { 
            "type": "node", 
            "request": "launch", 
            "name": "Jasmine Current File", 
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jasmine-ts/lib/index",
            "args": ["--config=src/spec/jasmine.json", "${file}"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
}
```

jasmine.json

```
{
    "spec_dir": "",
    "spec_files": [ "**/*app.component.spec.ts" ],
    "helpers": [ "helpers/**/*.js" ],
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": false
}
```

protractor.conf.js

```
// @ts-check
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [ './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts' ],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.e2e.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "test-app": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/test-app",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": false,
                        "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets" ],
                        "styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "10kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "test-app:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "test-app:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "test-app:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets" ],
                        "styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [ "tsconfig.app.json", "tsconfig.spec.json", "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json" ],
                        "exclude": [ "**/node_modules/**" ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "test-app:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "test-app:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "test-app"
}
```

folder structure as shown below

[image: angular project structure]

[image: jasmine.json path]